# Alter failhard variable in Salt on a temporary basis

Tags: salt-stack

Good afternoon,

We are running a Salt master with several production minions. In order to avoid unnecessary accidents, we have set `failhard=True` in the `/etc/salt/master` config file. This stops execution of a state on any non-green output.

The problem with this is that this global configuration also halts execution of states where `test=True` is set, so makes debugging new states tricky, especially when running shell commends which will produce a yellow result each time, halting the state.

I'd like to be able to do something akin to the follwing, which doesn't seem to work:

```
salt hostname state.highstate test=True failhard=False
```

Does anyone know of a way of either changing this variable non-globally, as above, or asking salt to failhard only on red output (ideally only when test=True is passed?)